# Emulate hard disk in .NET

Tags: .net, emulation, hard-drive

Is there a way to emulate a disk drive in .NET, intercepting read/write/lock operations?
I would like to create something with a front-end similar to [GMail Drive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GMail_Drive) in C#.

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the Eldos [Callback File System](http://eldos.com/cbfs/) myself for this purpose, but although it's good, it's not exactly cheap.

There are some free/cheap projects as well, and I'm sure one of them was mentioned in a similar question on SO recently -- can't find it anymore at the moment, though. Stability tends to be a major issue, though, as layered Windows file system drivers aren't trivial.

Answer (score 7):

On Linux you can use the Mono.Fuse API (http://www.jprl.com/Projects/mono-fuse.html) to implement .NET-based file systems with user-land code.

Answer (score 2):

You could see how http://www.truecrypt.org/ is doing it. It's doing exactly that either by using files or by using a drive or a partition. And then it mounts the file as if it were a real drive. Now, probably that the source code is a bit complex ;)

Answer (score 0):

Not really, .Net sits on top of OS functionality like disk access to give you things like managed file accessors.You could write all of it in managed C#, but you'd need unmanaged calls to make the OS treat it like another drive.

All the shell extension stuff is COM: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc147467(VS.85).aspx

You could, however, write a .Net desktop app that allowed drag-drop from explorer and that looked like a file system view.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [EZNamespaceExtension for .NET](http://www.ssware.com/eznamespaceextensions/eznamespaceextensions.htm). This gives you integration with Windows Explorer. Not too expensive given that the license is per developer and not distribution.

**Update**
Big problem with EZNamespaceExtension.NET. It hasn't been updated for a long time. LogicNP seems to have lost their interest in EZNamespaceExtension.NET because there hasn't been a release with new a handful of features since 2010. No .NET 4 support and no support for Windows 8 ribbon toolbar

Answer (score 0):

I've just checkout [EZNamespaceExtension for .NET](http://www.ssware.com/eznamespaceextensions/eznamespaceextensions.htm) with the above link. It seem that they keep up to date as release 2013 version. But not sure that can answer the question of Showing as a Drive in Explorer.exe (AFAIK. it can't show as drive letter)