# Access Gmail Drive through C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, file-io, gmail, virtual-drive

First, let me tell you about Gmail Drive: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GMail_Drive

Now what I want is to store some data in a text file or so, timely to this GMail Drive. I am looking for your help on how to do this.

I would appreciate alternatives that you recommend, but be thankful if you provide an insight to this problem only without any alternatives.

Comment: the wiki is saying that extension abstracts the "drive" as a share, which leads me to believe regular file i/o would cause the drivers to save the file.. should be very simple

Comment: @zanlok: I thought the same thing, but the only thing that caught my eye is where it says that it doesn't assign the virtual drive a drive letter. I have never used the Gmail Drive, but I'm not sure how exactly how the standard file I/O functions would work with it if this is the case.

Comment: Something similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138080/emulate-hard-disk-in-net , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011190/how-do-i-programmatically-access-system-folder-created-by-gmail-drive but still i am clueless..

Comment: bad news: with DriveInfo.GetDrives() we can not get any information about Gmail Drive,
test in windows7 + visual studio 2010 c# express

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's [a](http://www.koders.com/php/fidC39807AB3F869909EC63C3D927648FB41C61EBA5.aspx?s=%22gmail+drive%22) php project for accesing gmail drive , but i have no idea about accessing it through C# .NET

Is this [image] what you are looking for ?
Then i would recommend above php solution, no idea for .NET

Comment: Sorry, i dunno php. Looking forward for .NET solution only, if any. Thanks

Comment: @Patrick, the link you have mentioned accessing gmail from php. This is nothing to do with GDrive...

Comment: @Ramesh I don't much about gmail drive but i have used it and to my knowledge it stores user files as an attachments to corresponding email ID. Same happens in above php project and for your reference : http://sourceforge.net/projects/pgd/

Comment: pgd is a plugin you can use within your php web app to show the gmail files. But gdrive is windows extenstion where you can have a physical like (virtual) drive to store and view gmail file. I think drive in PhpGmailDrive and GDrive confused you... no worries.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying but still i guess at the end both works the same i.e. saves files in the form of gmail attachments and looking only for .NET solution only.

Comment: This is not what the OP asked for.

Answer (score 1):

From Gdrive,

> GMail Drive is a Shell Namespace
>   Extension that creates a virtual
>   filesystem around your Google GMail
>   account, allowing you to use GMail as
>   a storage medium.

so this is simply a virtual drive. There is a way to access virtual drives from c#, using [System.IO.IsolatedStorage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

And check out this [Performing Isolated Storage Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8dzkff1s%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)  for How to use isolated storage from your application.

Note: I dont have any experience with gdrive before. So it may or maynot work.

Comment: i hv never used System.IO.IsolatedStorage before can you provide some pseudo-code or so for the same.

Comment: I don't think the purpose of SO is to hand you a working solution, but to point you in the right direction. Ramesh may have hit on a better answer than mine, but check the links there, too.

Answer (score 1):

Even though there's no [drive letter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28VS.85%29.aspx), the volume should be [visible](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/33770326/filedirectory-paths-using-volume-name.aspx). Try the code below as a quick test, and then more info from ["here"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yk7a1b0.aspx) to see what's on the volume. Then, you should be able to extend all that to read/write files on it, as well.

```
using System.IO;
foreach( DriveInfo driveInfo in DriveInfo.GetDrives() ) {
   // ...
}
```

Comment: I am only getting my physical drives DriveInfo.GetDrives()  and NOT gamil drive. how should i go ahead with ?

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this personally, but heard very good things

[Mail.net](http://www.lesnikowski.com/mail/)

The author is always update, he also on twitter alot.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for an alternative but as i already said, i am specifically looking for Gmail Drive and C# .NET solution to access it.