# Virtual Drive Mapped to Program

Tags: c#, .net, c++, windows, shell

Would it be possible to create a program (.NET preferably) to create a virtual drive letter, but when it is read, written to, or browsed an independent program deals with what is returned?

Although you could do it by mapping a drive to a TCP server, webDAV or something like that, I'm wondering if it could be done with internal links.

This would be used for protected storage. The program does stream encryption and decryption of all the files in the drive (as they're read by all kinds of programs) if the program has had a password put into it.

Comment: you are looking more to a device driver than a *program*

Comment: Doubt it's totally possible in .Net. See similar question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138080/emulate-hard-disk-in-net

Comment: There a drivers that forward to a userspace program for file system operations. But I don't know if there is a free one.

Comment: But I wouldn't want to do that for encryption. An encryption program needs low level features, for example to unmount on hibernation, or preventing the key from being swapped to disk. Encrypting the system partition probably isn't possible with this approach either. Why don't you just use TrueCrypt for that?

Comment: @CodeInChaos I don't want to use TrueCrypt because its an idea that I was wondering exactly how it worked. Might not even use it, just wondering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're talking about is a storage device driver, which is how programs such as Daemon Tools and TrueCrypt accomplish such "virtual" drives.

You may not have to delve into the kernel to accomplish this, though. Microsoft supply a Windows User-Mode Driver Framework, which is designed to simplify the development of certain common Windows driver types. From what I can tell, you should be able to develop a virtual storage driver using the user-mode driver framework. As long as you're not directly interacting with hardware (like a kernel-mode device driver does), you should be fine. However, you won't be able to do this in C#. You'd probably have to use C, though you might get away with C++.

Comment: Cheers man, sounds good. You wouldn't happen to know of any references showing the code of such a device on a basic level as a start point would you?

Comment: OSR Online is a great community for Windows driver development. You may also want to check out Windows Internals 5 by Mark Russinovich for a very detailed background on Windows kernel internals. A quick google search for "windows driver development" will give you the rest.

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell already supports something like this with its Provider model. Certificate store, Active Directory, IIS configuration, SharePoint, ... are all made to look file system like, using the same commands to query and update.

This is at the heart of PowerShell. `$foo` is the value of variable `foo`, `${c:\foo.txt}` is the content of file `C:\foo.txt` but used just like a variable. Equally `dir HKLM:\Software` lists the child keys of that registry key.

You can write you own providers.

Comment: Isn't this doing the inverse of what he asked? i.e. taking an existing device and making it a file, instead of taking an existing file and turning it into a device.

Comment: @Polynomial No. A provider can take a file and make it look like a complete file system. There is a provider that works across IE's RSS support – a series of files in IE's data folders are transformed into a more user format (`FeedStore` provider is part of [PSCX](http://pscx.codeplex.com/)).

Answer (score 1):

There is an open source program, [WinCDEmu](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wincdemu/) that can mount an ISO image to a virtual drive. I suppose you'll be able to examine the sources to figure out how to provide a virtual drive that does what you want. The project is written in C++.

It is based on [BazisLib](http://bazislib.sysprogs.org/), which is a framework for simplifying windows driver development.